# What's wrong with my edit? I'm trying to edit a spoiler js code (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to edit this spoiler js code, to add a div to be the button for each spoiler. Here's the original code (it uses jQuery):

```
function spoilerToggle() {
  var sliderID = "#spoiler-slider" + $(this).attr("slider-id");
  if($(sliderID).css("display") == "none") {
    $(this).text("[-]");
     $(this).attr("title", "Hide Spoiler")          
  }
  else {
     $(this).text("[+]");
     $(this).attr("title", "Show Spoiler")
  }
  $(sliderID).slideToggle('fast');
}
function addSpoilers() {
  $("div.spoiler-text").each(addBlockSpoiler);
  $(".block-spoiler-toggle").click({"spoiler": "block"}, spoilerToggle);
}
function addBlockSpoiler(i) {
  $(this).attr("id", "spoiler-slider" + i);
  $("<div class='block-spoiler'>spoiler <span class='block-spoiler-toggle' title='Show Spoiler' slider-id='" + i + "'>[+]</span></div>").insertBefore(this);
}
$(document).ready(addSpoilers);
```

Now, if I use this, all divs with class="spoiler-text" will have a div with "spoiler" text before, and a [+] or a [-] to open/close show/hide them.
I'm trying to edit it, like this:

```
function spoilerToggle() {
  var sliderID = "#spoiler-slider" + $(this).attr("slider-id");
  if($(sliderID).css("display") == "none") {
    $(this).text("[-]");
     $(this).attr("title", "Hide Spoiler")          
  }
  else {
     $(this).text("[+]");
     $(this).attr("title", "Show Spoiler")
  }
  $(sliderID).slideToggle('fast');
}
function addSpoilers() {
  $("div.spoiler-text").each(addBlockSpoiler);
  $(".block-spoiler-toggle").click({"spoiler": "block"}, spoilerToggle);
}
function addBlockSpoiler(i) {
  $(this).attr("id", "spoiler-slider" + i);
  // $("<div class='block-spoiler'>spoiler <span class='block-spoiler-toggle' title='Show Spoiler' slider-id='"+i+"'>[+]</span></div>").insertBefore(this);
  $("div.block-spoiler-toggle").each($("div.block-spoiler-toggle").attr("slider-id", i));
}
$(document).ready(addSpoilers);
```

This should find the div with class="block-spoiler-toggle", add to them "slider.id=0" or 1 or 2, etc.. to use them to show/hide my spoilers divs.
Obviously, in my html page, the number of div.spoiler-text and div.block-spoiler-toggle will be the same, so the ids will be the same too.

But this isn't working and I cannot understand why.
Could someone help me? What's wrong with my edit?

Thanks in advance :D

EDIT:
my html page: http://uxiedex.altervista.org/pokedex-xy/
the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3xZA/

Comment: How about posting your HTML and a jsFiddle?

Comment: Im confused. The title asks one question (which people have tried answering below) but the text asks an unrelated one. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jamiec yes, I'm sorry, that was another question. I'm going to edit the title. The text is correct.

Comment: @j08691 This is the page I'm trying it http://uxiedex.altervista.org/pokedex-xy/
This the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v3xZA/

Comment: You have a syntax error, thats why its not working. What you pass to `.each` must be a function. Check the javascript console in your jsfiddle

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you, that was the error! Thank you a lot :D

If you want to reply my question, I'll add the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
$("div.block-spoiler-toggle").each($("div.block-spoiler-toggle").attr("slider-id", i));
```

The error is caused by the fact that jQuery's [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method must take a function, so you probably wanted this:

```
$("div.block-spoiler-toggle").each(function(){
    $("div.block-spoiler-toggle").attr("slider-id", i))
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(  $('div').length  );
    // Or native js:
    alert( document.getElementsByTagName('div').length );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplified version.

```
$(function () {
  alert($('div').length);
});
```

1. `$(function () {})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function () {})`
2. All selectors use `document` as the root node so you don't need to specify `$(document).find()`

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;

    $(document).find('div').each(function(){
        count++;
    });

    alert(count);
}):
```

This should do it. Feel free to turn this into a function and call it within your existing code.

Comment: whats wrong with just `$('div').length`? Any need for the whole loop+counter?

Comment: I gave a downvote because its more complicated than needed. A loop through the while document can be very slow on large pages and jam the browser for a period

Comment: Going to add this: This method could be the prefered one if you want very exotic elements. Elements who are in certain elements, with some extra conditions and requirements which require a `each()` to check them with

Comment: @Martijn It's more complicated but it's not going to jam the browser.  The selector runs just as quickly as `$('div')` and stepping through a simple count++ is easy math for the JavaScript VM.  Still, it's more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: A loop-function on a selection will be slower than a property of a selection. But I could be wrong.